# What's the meaning of _mm512_mask_loadunpacklo_epi32?

Tags: x86, intel, intrinsics, avx512

I'm a beginner with the AVX-512, when I read the source code for an open source program, I found the following codes:

```
__m512i vecData1;
__mmask16 vecMask;
int32_t *addrF = (int32_t *)_mm_malloc(sizeof(int32_t), 64);
...
vecData1 = _mm512_mask_loadunpacklo_epi32(vecZero, vecMask, addrF);
vecData1 = _mm512_mask_loadunpacklo_epi32(vecData1, vecMask, addrF+16);
```

I try to find the [document](http://portal.nacad.ufrj.br/online/intel/compiler_c/common/core/index.htm#GUID-6EC40364-D092-414E-90F1-252FA7218CF0.htm), I got the following text

> The low 64-byte-aligned portion of the doubleword stream starting at the element-aligned address mt is loaded and expanded into the writemask-enabled elements of resulting doubleword vector, for which the initial values are copied from v1_old vector. The number of set bits in the writemask determines the length of the doubleword stream, as each doubleword is mapped to exactly one of the doubleword elements in the resulting vector, skipping over writemasked elements of the resulting vector.

> This function only transfers those doublewords (if any) in the stream that occur at or after the first 64-byte-aligned address following mt (that is, in the low cache line of the memory stream for the current implementation). Elements in the resulting vector that do not map to those stream doublewords are left unchanged (taken from v1_old). The _mm512_loadunpackhi_epi32 function is used to load the part of the stream at or after the first 64-byte-aligned address preceding mt.

> In conjunction with _mm512_loadunpackhi_epi32, this function is useful for re-expanding data that was packed into a queue. Also in conjunction with _mm512_loadunpackhi_epi32, it allows unaligned vector loads (that is, vector loads that are only element-wise, not vector-wise, aligned). The typical intrinsic sequence to perform an unaligned vector load would be:
> `v1 = _mm512_loadunpacklo_epi32(v1, mt);`
> `v1 = _mm512_loadunpackhi_epi32(v1, mt+64);`

But I still couldn't understand the meaning of this instruction, especially `doubleword stream`, can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `_mm512_mask_loadunpacklo_epi32` isn't an intrinsic and you haven't shown the definition.  It's not even one of Intel's SVML library functions that are also part of their intrinscs guide (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html).  The text you quote talks about it as a function, presumably they define it somewhere in that article.

Comment: The link in your question (http://portal.nacad.ufrj.br/online/intel/compiler_c/common/core/index.htm#GUID-6EC40364-D092-414E-90F1-252FA7218CF0.htm) is the documentation for `_mm512_sllv_epi32`  on some random copy of Intel's compiler docs.  It doesn't contain the text you're quoting.

Comment: A "doubleword stream" is just an array of 32-bit elements in memory.  The word "stream" implies we might not know how long it is, maybe that's why we're using masked loads.  For example a "byte stream" is a concept you might hear about in network protocols or serializing / deserializing to a file.  A dword stream just has wider elements.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you very much. The page link is correct, but the position is embarrassing. I have missed that the intrinsic is belong to Intel® Initial Many Core Instructions. I'll try to find in the correct document.

Comment: Oh, first-gen Xeon Phi, KNF (Knight's Ferry), long since discontinued.  It had a 512-bit vector instruction set similar to AVX-512, but with some differences.  With AVX-512 intrinsics, you'd just use a masked 512-bit load and a separate `_mm512_maskz_unpacklo_epi32` and hope the compiler folded it into a memory source operand for `vpunpckldq zmm {k1}{z}, zmm, [mem]`

Comment: You can right-click on entries in the menu on the left to get a URL for the entry you want.  Left-clicking updates the other pane without changing the browser's URL.  http://portal.nacad.ufrj.br/online/intel/compiler_c/common/core/GUID-87ACEAE2-EF0B-400D-963F-F66D3535BB81.htm or http://portal.nacad.ufrj.br/online/intel/compiler_c/common/core/index.htm#GUID-87ACEAE2-EF0B-400D-963F-F66D3535BB81.htm